# Which method called before app.ready() in electron

Tags: javascript, performance, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

```
const { app } = require('electron')
```

I want to call `app.disableHardwareAcceleration()` before app.ready()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this call app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");

app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

app.on("ready", () => {
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
    });

    window.loadURL("about:blank");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ElectronJS has event "will-finish-launching". That will be invoked when the application has finished basic startup.

```
app.on('will-finish-launching', () => { ... })
```

Comment: Yes, but bro according to doc, Emitted when the application has finished basic startup. On Windows and Linux, the will-finish-launching event is the same as the ready event